# How to pass two different JSON Objects to processFinish at two different times

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have this `MainActivity` which does two `HTTP` calls and return the JSON object back to the MainActivity class. I have seperately implemented the AsyncTask class and used the `AsyncResponse` interface to get the JSON object to the `MainActivity` by using the `processFinish` function call.

At first I came up with one HTTP call which worked perfectly.
Secondly I wanted to do another HTTP call in the same activity class. So I edit the code to cater the second HTTP call.

When I run the application, only the first HTTP call is working. When I call the second HTTP call it throws an `exception` saying `reference to a null object`

Then I checked by logging the `onPostExecute` method which calls the processFinish function. There I could see the JSON Object. So, that means the second JSON object doesn't get to the `processFinish`

How do I manage the second HTTP call? Please help me! I am new to Android.

Following is my `AsyncTask` class...

```
public class ServiceHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    String startStationID;
    String endStationID;
    String searchDate;
    String startTime;
    String endTime;

    public ServiceHandler(String startStationID, String endStationID, String searchDate, String startTime, String endTime) {
        this.startStationID = startStationID;
        this.endStationID = endStationID;
        this.searchDate = searchDate;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(JSONObject output);
    }

    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

    public ServiceHandler(AsyncResponse delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];
        JSONObject JSON_Object = null;


        if (method.equals("getStations")) {

            JSON_Object = Constants.apiCall("http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/railway/1.0/station/getAll?lang=en");

        } else if (method.equals("searchTrains")) {
            JSON_Object = Constants.apiCall("http://api.lankagate.gov.lk:8280/railway/1.0/train/searchTrain?" +
                    "startStationID="+this.startStationID+"&" +
                    "endStationID="+this.endStationID+"&" +
                    "searchDate="+this.searchDate+"&" +
                    "startTime="+this.startTime+"&" +
                    "endTime="+this.endTime+"&" +
                    "lang=en");
        }
        return JSON_Object;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
        try{
Log.d("onPostExecute",obj.toString());
            delegate.processFinish(obj);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("onPostExecute",e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Following is my `processFinish` function...

```
    @Override
    public void processFinish(JSONObject output) {
        Log.d("processFinish",output.toString());

        if(!isSearchClicked) {
            //Get all the stations...
            if (output != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = output.getJSONObject("RESULTS");
                    output = null;
                    JSONArray dataArray = obj.getJSONArray("stationList");

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object1 = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String stationID = object1.getString("stationID");
                        String stationName = object1.getString("stationName");

                        stationNames.add(stationName);
                        stationIDs.add(stationID);
//                    stations.put(stationID,stationName);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Connection Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }else {
            //search click action...
            if (output != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Searched!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                try {
                    JSONObject obj = output.getJSONObject("RESULTS");
                    JSONArray directTrains = obj.getJSONArray("directTrains");


//                    Log.d("array size",String.valueOf(directTrains.length()));
//                    for (int i = 0; i < directTrains.length(); i++) {
//                        JSONObject object1 = directTrains.getJSONObject(i);
//
//                        String stationID = object1.getString("stationID");
//                        String stationName = object1.getString("stationName");
//                        Log.d("JArr", stationID + " : " + stationName);
//
//                        stationNames.add(stationName);
//                        stationIDs.add(stationID);
////                    stations.put(stationID,stationName);
//                    }
//                    Log.d("stationNames", stationNames.toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Connection Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("output",output.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Following is my first HTTP call...

```
ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler(this);

String method = "getStations";
sh.execute(method);
```

Following is my second HTTP call...

```
String method = "searchTrains"
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler(startStationID,endStationID,searchDate,startTime,endTime);
        sh.execute(method);
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where is the second http call?

Comment: @PedroVarela i have added the HTTP calls at the end..

Comment: read my answer, change those asynctask and read about intent services and broadcast receivers (using the local broadcast not global broadcast)

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand exactly what your problem is. There are few things I suggest you to do.

Here I go.

1. Don't use AsyncTask to make your http calls , use an intent services instead.
2. Use a OkHTTP library for your networking [source](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
3. On your intent service send local broadcast with LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast your results from the http call.
4. Register broadcastsReceivers within your activities or fragments that will listen for those broadcasts that comes from the intent service

Why not to use AsyncTask: Because of configuration change - if you rotate your device you will lose that network calls-

Read about intent services [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)